# Postgres jsonb support in spring data

Tags: postgresql, spring-data, jsonb

As Postgres offers nosql flavor along with rdbms by jsonb data type I was looking into springboot and spring data to see what opinionated frameworks suggest on use of that jsonb. I was looking into spring data for nosql supported technology and I dont see postgres now that is because its not nosql. But how we expect to write different nosql like queries for postgres jsonb field using spring data like we can using Mongorepository...if someone can throw some example/blog it will be great.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51301896/12488082 answer your question?