# how to store PostgreSQL jsonb using SpringBoot + JPA?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I'm working on a migration software that will consume unknown data from REST services.

I already think about use MongoDB but I decide to not use it and use PostgreSQL.

After read [this](https://blog.codeship.com/unleash-the-power-of-storing-json-in-postgres/) I'm trying to implement it in my SpringBoot app using Spring JPA but I don't know to map `jsonb` in my entity.

Tried [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-collections-using-jpa-and-hibernate/) but understood nothing!

Here is where I am:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface DnitRepository extends JpaRepository<Dnit, Long> {

    @Query(value = "insert into dnit(id,data) VALUES (:id,:data)", nativeQuery = true)
    void insertdata( @Param("id")Integer id,@Param("data") String data );

}
```

and ...

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    DnitRepository dnitRepository;  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dnit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testBig() {
        dnitRepository.insertdata(2, someJsonDataAsString );
    }

}
```

and the table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.dnit
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    data jsonb,
    CONSTRAINT dnit_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

How can I do this?

**Note: I don't want/need an Entity to work on. My JSON will always be String but I need jsonb to query the DB**

Comment: Then why use JPA at all, you aren't using it now (as you are writing native queries already).

Comment: You're right. But I want to take advantage of the very simple configuration-less of Spring in this case... Creating all connection stuff is boring. Is there some way to get the `Session` or something to run the query without the `@Repository`?

Comment: What has configuration JDBC to do with Spring Data JPA? Where dit you get that idea? Spring Data JPA has nothing to do with configuring a datasource and JdbcTemplate. Both of them are automatically configured even without using Spring Data JPA?

Comment: Spring Data JPA using SpringBoot just asking me for an Interface and an URL connection in `application.properties`. If I don't use it I need to configurate all in a old fashion way (Session, DAO, Connection, EntityManager, etc... ) and I don't want to.

Comment: Again where did you get that impression.. No you don't... Spring Boot wills till configure that, Spring Data JPA isn't a requirement for that!.... And you don't need JPA... You aren't even using it, then why even bother with it.

Comment: Anyway.... Solved using a database `insert` function to wrap the `jsonb` type exposing the function parameter as a text and then inserting as jsonb. Just using the `@Query` as `select insert_data( my_string_json )`. Done.

Comment: @M. Deinum I think is not enough just tell me `I don't need to use`. Plase tell us `how`...

Comment: So instead of making things easier you choose to make it more complex, by "using" a framework but actually bypassing it, all due to a misunderstanding of how the configuration works?

Comment: Give us some code please?

Comment: As I stated by simply NOT using it and use a plain `JdbcTemplate` that is all you need to execute the same SQL statement.

Comment: Instead of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` add `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` leave the datasource stuff. Instead of calling the method on your interface (ditch the interface) do `jdbcTemplate.executeUpdate("insert into dnit(id, data) VALUES (?,to_json(?))", id, data);`

Comment: Ah! Now I got it! Can you post as an answer? ( paste and edit my controller with your solution will be great )

Comment: Still someone looking for solution this might work https://stackoverflow.com/a/65489772/17148998

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are making things overly complex by adding Spring Data JPA just to execute a simple insert statement. You aren't using any of the JPA features.  Instead do the following

1. Replace `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` with `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`
2. Remove your `DnitRepository` interface
3. Inject `JdbcTemplate` where you where injecting `DnitRepository`
4. Replace `dnitRepository.insertdata(2, someJsonDataAsString );` with `jdbcTemplate.executeUpdate("insert into dnit(id, data) VALUES (?,to_json(?))", id, data);`

You were already using plain SQL (in a very convoluted way), if you need plain SQL (and don't have need for JPA) then just use SQL.

Ofcourse instead of directly injecting the `JdbcTemplate` into your controller you probably want to hide that logic/complexity in a repository or service.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Many thanks. The Service will be a must have indeed. Wait... "convoluted way" ??

Comment: Well convoluted as in trying to shoehorn it into JPA without actually using JPA and using a layer that you don't need.

Answer (score 76):

> Tried [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-collections-using-jpa-and-hibernate/) but understood nothing!

To fully work with **`jsonb`** in **Spring Data JPA** (Hibernate) project with Vlad Mihalcea's [hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) lib you should just do the following:

1) Add this lib to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2) Then use its types in your entities, for example:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private List<Child> children;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Bio bio;

    public Parent(String name, List children, Bio bio) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children;
        this.bio = bio;
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Child implements Serializable {
    private String name;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Bio implements Serializable {
    private String text;
}
```

Then you will be able to use, for example, a simple `JpaRepository` to work with your objects:

```java
public interface ParentRepo extends JpaRepository<Parent, Integer> {
}
```

```java
parentRepo.save(new Parent(
                     "parent1", 
                     asList(new Child("child1"), new Child("child2")), 
                     new Bio("bio1")
                )
);
```

```java
Parent result = parentRepo.findById(1);
List<Child> children = result.getChildren();
Bio bio = result.getBio();
```

Comment: That's the problem. As I said at first: `I'm working on a migration software that will consume unknown data from REST services` so I can't create any entity. If I have entities then there's no need for JSON. The M. Deinum solution is far the best.

Comment: @MagnoC my answer isn't a solution. It's just help with 'hibernate-types' ;)

Comment: what would we do if there is no vlad in this world?

Comment: @Cepr0  What if I just want to map that with JsonObject, not any custom class?

Comment: For Hibernate 5.6 follow this: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/

Answer (score 15):

There are already several answers and I am pretty sure they work for several cases. I don't wanted to use any more dependencies I don't know, so I look for another solution.
The important parts are the **AttributeConverter** it maps the jsonb from the db to your object and the other way around. So you have to annotate the property of the jsonb column in your entity with **@Convert** and link your **AttributeConverter** and add **@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")** as well, so JPA knows what type this is in the DB. This should already make it possible to start the spring boot application. But you will have issues, whenever you try to **save()** with the **JpaRepository**. I received the message:

> PSQLException: ERROR: column "myColumn" is of type jsonb but
> expression is of type character varying.

> Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

This happens because postgres takes the types a little to serious.
You can fix this by a change in your conifg:

> datasource.hikari.data-source-properties: stringtype=unspecified

> datasource.tomcat.connection-properties: stringtype=unspecified

Afterwards it worked for me like a charm, and here is a minimal example.
I use JpaRepositories:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {
}
```

The Entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Convert;

public class MyEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  protected Integer id;

  @Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  private MyJsonObject jsonContent;

}
```

The model for the json:

```
public class MyJsonObject {

  protected String name;

  protected int age;

}
```

The converter, I use Gson here, but you can map it however you like:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MyConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyJsonObject, String> {

  private final static Gson GSON = new Gson();

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(MyJsonObject mjo) {
    return GSON.toJson(mjo);
  }

  @Override
  public MyJsonObject convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    return GSON.fromJson(dbData, MyJsonObject.class);
  }
}
```

SQL:

```
create table my_entity
(
    id serial primary key,
    json_content jsonb

);
```

And my application.yml (application.properties)

```
  datasource:
    hikari:
      data-source-properties: stringtype=unspecified
    tomcat:
      connection-properties: stringtype=unspecified
```

Comment: Great answer! Saved me tons of time. One thing that didn't work for me as described here was setting the `stringtype` to `unspecified`; only way I could get it done is providing explicitly in the connection url, e.g. `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?stringtype=unspecified`

Comment: Thanks Arthur, Adding this parameter to my connection string did the trick

Comment: What to do if the JSON type object class (MyJsonObject) is a list of MyJsonObject class?

Answer (score 4):

For this case, I use the above tailored converter class, you are free to add it in your library. It is working with the EclipseLink JPA Provider.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.postgresql.util.PGobject;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;

@Converter
public final class PgJsonbToMapConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, ? extends Object>, PGobject> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PgJsonbToMapConverter.class);
    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public PGobject convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, ? extends Object> map) {
        PGobject po = new PGobject();
        po.setType("jsonb");

        try {
            po.setValue(map == null ? null : MAPPER.writeValueAsString(map));
        } catch (SQLException | JsonProcessingException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Cannot convert JsonObject to PGobject.");
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return po;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ? extends Object> convertToEntityAttribute(PGobject dbData) {
        if (dbData == null || dbData.getValue() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return MAPPER.readValue(dbData.getValue(), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
            });
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Cannot convert JsonObject to PGobject.");
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Usage example, for an entity named `Customer`.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "web", name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Convert(converter = PgJsonbToMapConverter.class)
    private Map<String, String> info;

    public Customer() {
        this.id = null;
        this.info = null;
    }

    // Getters and setter omitted.
```

Comment: Can Any one say me how to retrieve a data matching to a object present in the Jsonb Column

Comment: This is a different question, you may find a similar question or add your own in order to get an answer. You probably need to configure properly the `where` section of your query.

Comment: Using Hibernate I receive the error `column "info" is of type jsonb but expression is of type bytea`. Has anyone managed to use this solution with Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **R2DBC** you can use dependency `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql`, and use type `io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json` in your member attributes of an entity class, e.g.:

```
public class Rule {
    @Id
    private String client_id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Json publish_acl;
    private Json subscribe_acl;
}
```