# How to select data in spring boot using jpa based on where condition of jsonb column of postgres(without native query)?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, jsonb

I have Postgres database with jsonb field. I have used Predicate list for where condition with criteria builder in jpa. Now, I want to fetch JSON data stored in a database based on multiple where cause along with JSON. How it could be possible to do?

[Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5SFn.png)

```
private List<Predicate> whereClause(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Root<KafkaLog> kafkaLog,
  KafkaLogSearchDto search) {
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
if (search.getTopic() != null && !search.getTopic().isEmpty()) {
  Expression<String> literal =
      criteriaBuilder.literal("%" + search.getTopic().toUpperCase() + "%");
  predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(kafkaLog.get("topic")), literal));
}
if (search.getOffset() != null) {
  predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(kafkaLog.get("offset"), search.getOffset()));
}
if (search.getResourceId() != null) {
  predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(kafkaLog.get("invoiceId"), search.getResourceId()));
}
if (search.getPartition() != null) {
  predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(kafkaLog.get("partition"), search.getPartition()));
}
if (search.getStatus() != null) {
  predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(kafkaLog.get("status"), search.getStatus()));
}
if (search.getCreatedAtFrom() != null && search.getCreatedAtTo() != null) {
  predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(
      criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(kafkaLog.get("createdAt").as(Date.class),
          search.getCreatedAtFrom()),
      criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(kafkaLog.get("createdAt").as(Date.class),
          search.getCreatedAtTo())));
}
if (search.getPayload() != null && !search.getPayload().isEmpty()) {
  Expression<String> literal =
      criteriaBuilder.literal("%" + search.getPayload().toUpperCase() + "%"); 



}
return predicates;
```

}

```
private CriteriaQuery<KafkaLog> getKafkaBySearchCriteria(KafkaLogSearchDto search, String orderBy,
  int sortingDirection) {
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<KafkaLog> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(KafkaLog.class);
Root<KafkaLog> kafkaLog = criteriaQuery.from(KafkaLog.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = whereClause(criteriaBuilder, kafkaLog, search);
criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));

if (orderBy == null || orderBy.isEmpty()) {
  orderBy = "topic";
}
Expression<?> orderColumn = kafkaLog.get(orderBy);
if (orderColumn != null) {
  if (sortingDirection == 0) {
    criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(orderColumn));
  } else if (sortingDirection == 1) {
    criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(orderColumn));
  }
}
return criteriaQuery;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

apparently, custom data type support down to the JDBC/database level is not part of JPA itself. For just reading the JSON you might be able to do it with an entity mapping to `String` (if the JPA implementation does allow that).

However, you have some alternatives:

1. If you need to stick with JPA, you can implement a converter to handle the JSON for you (either generic as in this article or more specific - as you like): [Using JPA with PostgreSQL JSON](https://notes.kartashov.com/2015/11/12/jpa-and-postgresql-json/)
2. If you can, ditch JPA and do it with JDBC/SQL directly, which gives you the full potential of PostgreSQL: [how to store PostgreSQL jsonb using SpringBoot + JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276703/how-to-store-postgresql-jsonb-using-springboot-jpa#51286727)

When reading the JSONB field, you can let the database do the conversion to String (as there is no direct JSON support in JDBC, yet) using explicit type conversion, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT payload::text FROM my_table WHERE ...
```

...or do some fancy filtering on the JSON field itself or return only a portion of the JSON data, aso.

Comment: Thanks, Ancoron for the reply. As you suggested I have already tried to convert it into the string but it's too much time consuming for Rest call. It takes nearly 45-50 sec to search in the database. Therefore, I became helpless in this scenario. Moreover, I can not use nativequery for particular payload column.

Comment: OK, then we'd need to see which actual SQL the JPA implementation generates out of the criteria query and then you should execute a `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) <your-sql-here>` and either edit your question (query too slow?) or create a new question for that. As I see it, you already have it functionally working, just that it's way too slow, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is example predicate to search jsonb with like clause :

predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.and(cb.like(cb.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", String.class, root.get("tags"), cb.literal(this.key)), "%"+ this.value + "%"  )));