# Set a parameter in Query

Tags: spring, postgresql, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query(
    value = """
            SELECT * 
            FROM transfer
            WHERE id = :id
                AND recipient -> 'phoneNumbers' @> '[{"number":":phoneNumber"}]'
        """,
    nativeQuery = true
)
fun find(
    @Param("multitransferId") multitransferId: UUID,
    @Param("phoneNumber") phoneNumber: String,
    pageable: Pageable
): List<Transfer>
```

After execute:

```
Hibernate: 
                SELECT * 
                FROM transfer
                WHERE id = ?
                    AND recipient -> 'phoneNumbers' @> '[{"number":":phoneNumber"}]'
```

Hello everyone. I'm doing a Json search in a table. I wrote a request, but it doesn't run, because I can't parse the value **'[{"number":":phoneNumber"}]'** . Because **:phoneNumber** is perceived as a string. How do I set this value correctly in a query?

UPDATE:

This is how the json example looks like

```
{
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "isDefault": true,
      "type": "MOBILE",
      "number": "3454654645"
    },
    {
      "isDefault": true,
      "type": "MOBILE",
      "number": "12423543645"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think he means that `:phoneNumber` is not replaced by the parameter `phoneNumber`

Comment: It depends what database engine you are querying, and what the datatypes are in your table. For example, Microsoft SQL Server allows fields to be set to the "JSON" datatype, and has a nice JSON_VALUE function that you could use to extract the "phoneNumber" field from your JSON, but other database engines don't have that, so you would probably need to write custom JSON-parsing code. Make your question better, e.g. specify the database engine you're using and exactly what your tables contain, then we can answer it.

Comment: It doesn't look like java. Please put appropriate tag.

Comment: What happends when you use `'[{"number": :phoneNumber}]'`? (no `"` around `:phonenumber`)

Comment: I use posgres. my query is working I checked, it is not set in @Query . That's how I understand it

Comment: @Lino Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json : Expected JSON value, but found ":".

Comment: @hulxfp Do you have a reason why you need to use spring-jpa? It could also be done using spring-jdbc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276703/how-to-store-postgresql-jsonb-using-springboot-jpa

Comment: This won't work as the `'[{"number":":phoneNumber"}]'` is interpreted as text due to the `'` being in the query. Hence parameter substitution won't work here. You might be able to use the [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) to make it easier to store the JSON and write a JPQL which does what you want.

Comment: Before trying the Hibernate Types, you could try the following query `SELECT * FROM transfer WHERE id = :id AND recipient -> 'phoneNumbers' ->> 'number' = :phoneNumber`.

Comment: @M.Deinum This solution is not suitable, since the "phoneNumbers" key has the value - an array

Comment: I added an example Json for which I am making a request

Comment: can escaping characters somehow?