# How can I Store JsonObject to Postgresql Database?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring-boot

Here I get JSON Data from my Local Directory Using JsonObject, What can I do To Store this JsonObject To my Postgresql Database?

Example data:

```json
{
  "emp_id":1017,
  "emp_name":"Nagesh",
  "emp_designation":"Manager",
  "department":"Java2Novice",
  "salary":30000,
  "direct_reports":["Nataraj G","Kalyan","Mahitha"],
  "address": {"street":"MG Road","city":"Bangalore"}
}
```

I have proper `Application.property` for Postgresql Connection

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springjson
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=secret
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**how can I store in db**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringNestedJsonToDbApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringNestedJsonToDbApplication.class,args);

  File jsonInputFile = new File("D:/sample.json");

            InputStream is;

            try {

                is = new FileInputStream(jsonInputFile);
                

                JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(is);
                

                JsonObject empObj = reader.readObject();
                System.out.println(empObj);
                reader.close();
             
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51301896/11928455

Answer (score 0):

Use the .toString() method of JSONObject to get the text and save.