# Spring boot Spring Data JPA postgres jsonb column INSERT/UPDATE

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jsonb

i'm struggling trying to update a record on a postgres table with a **jsonb** column.

What i'm trying to do with spring boot and JPA is running this statement that works great on postgres:

```
UPDATE data_report 
SET error_details  = error_details || '[{"error": "testError","record": {"start":"14:00","end":"20:00","id":"AAAA001","date":"2022-01-31"}}]'::jsonb
WHERE id = 91;
```

I've tried with Native Query:

```
   @Transactional
   @Modifying
   @Query(value = "UPDATE data_integration_report SET error_details = error_details || :errors ::jsonb WHERE id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    void updateErrorDetail(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("errors") String errors);
```

but I'm getting error saying that syntax is not correct because ::jsonb is not recognized

I've tried with EntityManager

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(
       "UPDATE data_integration_report SET error_details = error_details || :errors ::jsonb WHERE id = :id"
        ).setParameter("id", 91L)
        .setParameter("errors", data)
        .executeUpdate();
```

Even here i'm getting error on syntax.
I've also tried to remove **::jsonb** cast, but I'm receiving this error: "column is of type jsonb but expression is of type text"

I'm looking for some documentation or an example that can help me to find a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to store PostgreSQL jsonb using SpringBoot + JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276703/how-to-store-postgresql-jsonb-using-springboot-jpa)

Answer (score 3):

I think the immediate problem you are having is casting the incoming field incorrectly.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE data_integration_report SET error_details = error_details || :errors ::jsonb WHERE id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
void updateErrorDetail(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("errors") String errors);
```

`:errors ::jsonb` has a space, so it sees the `::` cast operation as a separate token. However, JPA will choke on `:errors::jsonb` (as I suspect you have discovered).

There are two ways to do a Postgres cast inside a query like this:

1. Escape the colons: `:error\\:\\:jsonb`
2. Use the `cast` function: `cast(:error as jsonb)`

#### However

There is an even better solution, and that is to use a hibernate type made for `jsonb` in your entity. The commonly accepted solution is this one:  [vladmihalcea /
hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types)