# Error updating JSONB column using native SQL query in Spring Boot with JPA and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, sql-update, jsonb

I am encountering issues while attempting to update a JSONB column in a PostgreSQL table using a native SQL query in a Spring Boot application with JPA. The JSONB column, named `type_counters`, stores a map of key-value pairs representing `types` and their respective counts. I need to update the count for a specific `type` in the JSONB column, following certain rules. However, I have tried various approaches, including parameter binding, concatenation, and using the EntityManager, but none of them have resolved the problem. I am seeking assistance to successfully update the JSONB column using native SQL queries with JPA and PostgreSQL.

**Table Structure:**
The relevant table, `stats`, has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE stats (
    id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    type_counters JSONB
);
```

**Example Data:**
Few sample entry in the `stats` table:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|   id            |     type_counters              |
----------------------------------------------------
|   "abc123"      |   {"type1": 1, "type2": 4}     |
----------------------------------------------------
|   "def123"      |   {"type1": 1, "type5": 4}     |
----------------------------------------------------
|   "ijk123"      |   {"type4": 2}                 |
----------------------------------------------------
```

**Repository Implementation: **

Here is the code for the `StatsRepository` interface (in kotlin):

```
@Repository
interface StatsRepository : CrudRepository<Stats, Long> {

    // Equivalent SQL query which runs fine from CMD: 
    // UPDATE stats SET type_counters = type_counters || CONCAT('{"type1":', COALESCE(type_counters->>'type1','0')::int + 1, '}')::jsonb WHERE id = 'abc123';

    @Modifying
    @Query(
        value = "update stats set type_counters = type_counters || CONCAT('{\"', ?2, '\":', COALESCE(type_counters->>?2, '0')::int + 1, '}')::jsonb where id = ?1",
        nativeQuery = true
    )fun incrementTypeCounter(id: String, typeId: String)
}
```

**Error or Exception**

```
ERROR [main] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":" Position: 109
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
....
...
```

**Objective:**
The goal is to increment the count for a specific type in the `type_coutners` JSONB column. For example, given `id = "abc123"` and `type_key = "type1", the updated` type_counters`should be`{"type1": 2}`.

**Previous Attempts:**
I have tried the following approaches without success:

1. Using JPA's `@Query` annotation with native SQL query and parameter binding.
2. Concatenating the SQL query string to update the JSONB column.
3. Using the `EntityManager` and the `createNativeQuery` method.
   However, all these attempts have resulted in syntax errors, `invalid resource usage exceptions`, or other issues.

I am looking for guidance on how to effectively update the JSONB column in the `stats` table using native SQL queries in Spring Boot with JPA and PostgreSQL. Any insights, alternative solutions, or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I fixed it referring to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74155022/172021):

Needed to add the escape on `:` type cast. Update code below:

```
@Repository
interface StatsRepository : CrudRepository<Stats, Long> {

    // Equivalent SQL query which runs fine from CMD: 
    // UPDATE stats SET type_counters = type_counters || CONCAT('{"type1":', COALESCE(type_counters->>'type1','0')::int + 1, '}')::jsonb WHERE id = 'abc123';

    @Modifying
    @Query(
        value = "update stats set type_counters = type_counters || CONCAT('{\"', ?2, '\":', COALESCE(type_counters->>?2, '0')\\:\\:int + 1, '}')\\:\\:jsonb where id = ?1",
        nativeQuery = true
    )fun incrementTypeCounter(id: String, typeId: String)
}
```