# Postgres jsonb with dynamic schema

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I have a use case where the data of an object differ based on its type. So I want to store this data with data type jsonb. I followed this [similar stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51301896/9973101) where they have mentioned the following steps.

1. Add following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Add following entities.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private List<Child> children;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Bio bio;

    public Parent(String name, List children, Bio bio) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children;
        this.bio = bio;
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Child implements Serializable {
    private String name;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Bio implements Serializable {
    private String text;
}
```

The problem with above example is that it is having fixed schema for the jsonb field. In my case, it is not a fixed schema and is a dynamic one. I tried the following code but it is not working following this [link](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils#hibernate-5), could someone please help to resolve this?

```
@lombok.Data
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Node {
    String type;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Data data;
}
```

```
@lombok.Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Data implements Serializable {
    @Type(type = "io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonType")
    private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
}
```